# Turning Off Drupal 7's Cache

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-modules

Is there a way to run Drupal 7 in a "non-cache" mode while developing new modules?  My specific need is to turn off any caching of modules and/or module information during development so I don't need to clear the cache when I make my changes, but generally when learning a new system I prefer its internal cache be off since I haven't yet learned what changes require a cache clearing, and what don't (i.e. "Am I doing this wrong, or are the old results just cached?"

Also, is there a way to quickly clear out the Drupal cache from the command line  (instead of having to use the application UI in the performance section)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and run `drush cc all` on the command line.
And/or install [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) and hover over the Drupal icon in the top left corner, then on "Flush all caches".
And finally you could install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and check the box that reads "rebuild the cache registry on each page load."

Comment: Awesome, just the tools I was looking for.  One follow up.  In the Devel module's configuration page I see a "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load", but I don't see a "rebuild the cache registry on each page load.".  After installing Devel, where can I find the setting you're talking about (or has it been renamed/removed from Drupal 7?)

Comment: Sorry, that box disappeared in D7.

Comment: Why it dissapeared??? I haven't so much trouble to clean cache with joomla before :S

Answer (score 4):

See http://drupal.org/node/797346.

Btw, already answered this some time ago at [How do I completely disable cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892573/drupal-7-how-to-completely-disable-cache)